# Set cookie in every request - SPRING

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cookies, spring-security

Im now developing simple spring boot web app..
Is there something in spring(filter) that check every request(headers)..
I want to check if there is cookie..
If there is cookie- nothing happend..
But if there is not it would create cookie...
Do i have to do this manually, so i put this in every function?
Or can i do something like global function, that got executed with every other request?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you have to use filters
you can try doing something like this

```
public class MyCookieFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    public static final String MY_COOKIE_NAME = "your-cookie-name";


    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        checkCookie(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    private void checkCookie(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse servletResponse) {
        boolean cookieExists = Arrays.stream(request.getCookies()).anyMatch(cookie -> cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(MY_COOKIE_NAME));
        if (!cookieExists) {
            String cookieValue = "your-cookie-value";
            Cookie newCookie = new Cookie(MY_COOKIE_NAME, cookieValue);
            servletResponse.addCookie(newCookie);
        }
    }
}
```

then add it in your security config

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
     ...
       .addFilter(new MyCookieFilter())
     ...
    }
```

Comment: Hello,thanks, this could work, but i have some issues. I have one more filter that work, that is working for filtering jwt, i have asigned it to spring security like this   http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class); but it gives me error: does not have a registered order and cannot be added without a specified order.Consider using addFilterBefore or addFilterAfter instead., so i tried filterbefore, and filterafter but error is same, so i added it into my jwt filter, there it works pretty well, but code become dirty,is it possible to use 2 filters in same time?

Comment: yes you can add ass many filters as you want, when you add filter make sure you respect the order describe in spring docs here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpSecurityBuilder.html#addFilter%28javax.servlet.Filter%29. for your own case i think you can use addFilterBefore jwtFilter